# Trying to find excel formula to seperate complex text in excel

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula

I am trying to find the most efficennt way to make the following into a single column

The text appears in 3 different ways, the value after === is what it should become.

```
LOT: 4 TYP: SP PLN: 262354 === 4SP262354
LOT: 2 RP: 909144 === 2RP909144
LOT: 174 SP: 199682 === 174SP199682
```

Assuming the text to split is all in column L3 I have the following

```
M is =MID(L3,5,FIND("TYP",L3)-6) ===  1
N is =MID(L3,FIND("TYP:",L3)+4,FIND("PLN",L3)) ===  SP PLN: 262354
O is =MID(N3,1,FIND(" PLN",N3)-1) === SP
P is =RIGHT(N3,FIND(": ",N3)-2) ===262354
```

It works for some but not others and not in cases where there is no "TYP".

In Python we can do from start char no to end char no i.e text[1:9] and use find to locate the value for 1 and 9 but mid works with start and number of characters from that point, and so it causes issues.

Comment: so the text to be shortened is all in one cell? You could try to Substitute the parts you want to cut out with ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
     SUBSTITUTE(
         SUBSTITUTE(
             SUBSTITUTE(
                 SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", ""), "TYP:", ""), "PLN:", ""), "LOT:", ""), ":", "")
```

The innermost substitution `SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "")` removes all whitespace.  The other replacements remove the following:

```
TYP:
PLN:
LOT:
:   <-- remove any stray commas
```

**Output:**

[image]

Of course, you could always handle this in another way.  You could use Excel's find a replace functionality from the drop down menu and just do each of these steps separately.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you Need to replace `LOT:`, `TYP:`, `PLN:` and `:` with "" like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(L3; ": "; ""); " LOT"; ""); " PLN"; ""); " TYP"; "")
```

maybe you have to Play around with the spaces a Little, but this should be a good starting Point